# Why is Compress option not available in Dbeaver Community Output

Tags: dbeaver

Why is Compress option not available in Dbeaver Community Output

It was availoable in previous versions but now it is blurred.
What is the option to fix this issue. I tried reinstalling also.But still option is not being enabled .